# How to apply functions to numpy 8 * 8 blocks?

Tags: python, numpy, dct

Now i have 512 * 512 * 3 numpy array, I want to apply a function to each 8 * 8 block, for example, a dct transform, is there any built_in module to do that? I tried to implement it in a naive way

```
for c in xrange(3):
    for x in xrange(0, 512, 8):
        for y in xrange(0, 512, 8):
            img[x:x + 8, y:y + 8, c] = dct_2d(img[x:x + 8, y:y + 8, c])
            img[x:x + 8, y:y + 8, c] = idct_2d(img[x:x + 8, y:y + 8, c])
```

Which takes long time to iterate and calculate.

Comment: You should it change it into 3*512*512. such that you access memory contiguously

Comment: Oh yep! You are right. Didn't properly check the increment. Then is a completely valid answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `reshape` to change the shape of the data to `(64, 8, 64, 8, 3)`. Then apply `dct()` to the two length == 8 axis:

```
from scipy.fftpack import dct
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(512, 512, 3)

b = a.reshape(64, 8, 64, 8, 3)

res = dct(dct(b, axis=1), axis=3)
```

Comment: I believe it is not exactly equivalent. As this will create non-overlapping windows. While what the OP asks are overlapping 8x8 windows at every index.

Comment: @imaluengo, are you sure? The for loop `for x in xrange(0, 512, 8)` has step 8.